# How to dispose the Win32 APIs in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, memory-management

I am using c#.net to develop a winform application.My winform application is using the below components
1)Win 32 dlls (using System.Runtime.InteropServices)
2)Timers(3 in count) (System.Timers)
3)Excel Interop

The memory of the application is not at all coming down .As timers are running continuosly so i cannot dispose the 
So would like to implement dispose patterns .

Is it necessary to dispose the win32 APIs apart from Excel interop.?
If necessary can you please suggest the best way to call and dispose the win32 APIs.
Some of the Win32 APIs Used in application are listed below.

```
    DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);


    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int netConnection, int val);


    [DllImport("Oleacc.dll")]
    private static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint dwObjectID, byte[] riid, ref Excel.Window ptr);


    [DllImport("WtsApi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WTSRegisterSessionNotification(IntPtr hWnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]int dwFlags);

    [DllImport("WtsApi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: These are just declarations. If you are leaking, it's in some other code. How about you make a small repro?

Comment: Can you describe in pseudocode what you're asking about?

Comment: @andlabs :  Below is the sample code  
`[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]  
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();`  

`public class WinAPI  
{  

public void GetActiveWindowHandle  
{  
  IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;  

   handle = GetForegroundWindow();  

}  



}`  

In the above class i am using the GetForegroundWindow() API .  I am using it ,but not releasing the memory realted to it.  
Can you suggest the way how to dispose the WInAPIs used in the application.

Comment: For `GetForegroundWindow()` and `GetActiveWindow()`, nothing. Those functions return handles to resources that already exist (and in the case of the former, might not even be *your* windows). You do not have to (and indeed, should not) explicitly free them. If you had a class that let you create a window (that is, it wrapped `CreateWindow()` or any of the other `CreateXxx()` functions), *then* you would want to have a `Dispose()` that called the equivalent `DestroyXxx()`, `ReleaseXxx()`, or `CloseXxx()` functions should you have forgotten to do so yourself (though that might be a bug).

Answer (score -1):

The hWnd parameters in your function calls are all window handles. As a general rule, whenever you have finished using a window handle in the windows API, you need to explicitly release it using the CloseHandle function

Comment: `CloseHandle` is for kernel32 handles like file handles, mutex handles etc. It's not for user32 handles like window handles. Window handles don't need to be closed. You cannot leak `HWND`s in the way that you can leak `HANDLE`s. You can create windows and not destroy them. That would leak. But there's no evidence that is happening here. -1

Comment: @David Heffemam:Can you please suggest the proper way of using the win32 API in  c# application with out memory issues?